# remove duplicate a tag in 2 string?

Tags: php, string

I have 2 string like this:

```
$post_des = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui do <a href = "http://example.com/lorem_ipsum"> lorem ipsum </a> quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...'; 

$post_detail = '<a href = "http://example.com/lorem_ipsum">lorem ipsum </a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis purus finibus, ultricies diam at, faucibus nunc. Donec ac luctus ipsum,vitae <a href = "http://example.com/vehicula"> vehicula </a> erat. ' ;
```

and would like to remove all the duplicate ahref tags, like this:

```
$post_des = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui do <a href = "http://example.com/lorem_ipsum"> lorem ipsum </a> quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...'; 

$post_detail = 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec quis purus finibus, ultricies diam at, faucibus nunc. Donec ac luctus ipsum,vitae <a href = "http://example.com/vehicula"> vehicula </a> erat. ' ;
```

I tried to use DOM document and in_array, but there are about 2 milion tags (ex lorem ipsum, vehicular) . Is there any easier way?

Comment: you probably need to use something like substr in conjunction with array_splice, but I have to go for now so cant work it out exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using preg_match to get all the link tag ocurrences and iterating with them in order to delete (replacing with empty string) over the $post_detail. [Fiddle][1]

```
if(preg_match('/<a.*\>/',$post_des,$link_tags))
{
  foreach($link_tags as $link_tag)
  {
      preg_match('#<a[^>]+>(.+?)</a>#ims', $link_tag,$str);

      $post_detail = str_replace($link_tag,@$str[1],$post_detail);
  }
}
```

http://viper-7.com/Ul8BBN

Comment: Thanks @vivoconunxino for your reply . But i just want remove duplicate <a> tags but keep the word inside that tags. tried your code but it also remove my duplicate word ( lorem ipsum)

Comment: Can you check again? I tried echo both $post_des & $post_detail but nothing happed ? It sill have duplicate <a> tag is $post_detail

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, the first element of the preg_match results with $str contains the matched string, the next contains the contents. Updated

Comment: Thank you for your help . Your code help me alot :D